# Unexpected behavior when using Javascript to disable button

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, webforms

I have a page property

```
    private Boolean Status
    {
        get { return (Boolean)Session["st"]; }
        set { Session["st"] = value; }
    }
```

Then I have a button (inside a Update Panel) in the same page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="150px"   
              OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

& I have added this code, to page load to prevent multiple clicking of the button

```
       btnSubmit.Attributes.Add
          ("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + 
          Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, "").ToString());
```

If I set the session property (`Status`) to **true** and then click the button `btnSubmit`, the session property  is set to **false** automatically, If I remove the disabling code it works fine.

Any Idea what is causing this unexpected behavior?

---

**UPDATE 1** : This happens only with **Internet Explorer 10** (Windows 8), with Internet Explorer 8 & Google Chrome it works fine....!

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have this code in page load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{ 
    Status = false;
}
```

With Chrome when I click the Submit button it takes it as a PostBack so It works OK (does not run `Status = false;`), but with IE Submit click is not identified as a PostBack so it sets status (`Status = false`) in page load event.

Why the different browsers behave differently in this scenario? is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Which version of IE is failing? I don't think IE8 recognizes the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe IE is handling the submission of the disabled button in a way that causes ASP.NET to not see it as a postback. Try checking the request in each browser's respective inspectors (or fiddler) to see if they're sending the same data.

Comment: shouldnt it be `disabled=disabled`?

Comment: @davidkonrad Tried changing `true` to `disabled` but no avail.. :(